# Возможно ли ввести капчу в текстовом баузере (w3m) на linux?

Tags: linux, captcha

У сервера нет оконного варианта. Мне не нужно автоматическое распознавание и прочее. Просто вручную можно ли это сделать через консоль?

Comment: теоретически это возможно - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R2bMUtCOGko - но у меня не завелось

Comment: Эх, у меня тоже.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже столкнулся с данным вопросом при использовании w3m в консоли.

Решил данный вопрос поиском в консоли через поисковики, которые не требуют введения капчи.
Примеры таких поисковиков смотрите в обсуждении  ["Поисковики без капчи" на Linux.org](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/desktop/15140634)

Также могу порекомендовать консольную утилиту [ddgr](https://itsecforu.ru/2017/11/21/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-duckduckgo-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-linux/) от «DuckDuckGo» для поиска в Интернете.